# How can I seperate the values in the textbox to show in different labels using button?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, textbox

i want to be able to separate the values in a textbox and display the separated values in different labels using a button

this is what i want to happen:

1. input "Ac2O3" on textbox
2. Be able to separate "Ac", "2", "O", and "3".
3. Show the separated values in different textboxes using a button

im using visual basic 2012
im sorry im still new to this
thanks in advance!!

Comment: Is `Ac` always `Ac` or can it be anything? What have you tried?

Comment: im sorry, there i already edited it

Comment: u see, im trying to make a calculator for finding the percent composition of a compound

Comment: Welcom to Stack Overflow - You should probably include the code you've worked on to solve the problem do far- Have a look at this page to find out how to ask good questions [ask]....So you're trying to separate atomic symbols and their quantities out of a string and store them in labels. I presume then that the atomic symbols can be either one or two letters and the numbers can be one to 3 digits. Will there always be only two elements in the compound into the text box or could it be more complicated?

Comment: there can be up to 5 elements in a compound, as far as i know the longest  compound has 5 elements

Comment: Ah ok - sorry for the delay in replying - And what is the maximum number of digis for each element of the compounds? eg CO2 has only 1 digit for the numbers, but C6H12O6 has upto 2 digits for the compound - Also are there any compounds like (NH4)2SO4 where the number 2 refers to the number of groups of sulphate?

Comment: there wont be compounds that would refer to the number groups of a polyatomic ion.

Comment: OK Got it. Do you have a list of the compunds that I could test my code on when I get it going?

Answer (score 0):

You can access different character of the string with the index.

```
    Dim input As String = "Ac2O3"

    Dim part1 As String = input(0) & input(1)
    Dim part2 As String = input(2)
    Dim part3 As String = input(3)
    Dim part4 As String = input(4)
```

If you don't know how to handle the button event or how to display text in a textbox, that would be different questions.

Answer (score 0):

This code creates a structure called Element to make the results from the function clearer - add this to your main class that the function is going to be placed in. The main function takes a string as it's input and produced a list of  structures of Element as it's output. There probably are shorter ways to do this, but I'm a fairly basic programmer who likes a puzzle - hope this helps - Dont forget to accept the answer by clicking on the tick. If you have any queries please dont hesitate to ask

```
Structure Element
    Dim symbol As String
    Dim elementCount As Int16
End Structure


Function ParseFormula(ByVal compoundString As String) As List(Of Element)
    Dim tempParseFormula = New List(Of Element)
    Dim firstLetter As String = "[A-Z]"
    Dim secondLetter As String = "[a-z]"
    Dim number As String = "[0-9]"
    Dim tempElementCount As String = ""
    Dim maxIndex As String = compoundString.Length - 1
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim parsedElement As New Element
    While i <= maxIndex
        Dim tempChar As String = compoundString(i)
        Select Case True
            Case tempChar Like firstLetter
                parsedElement.symbol = parsedElement.symbol & tempChar
            Case tempChar Like secondLetter
                parsedElement.symbol = parsedElement.symbol & tempChar
            Case tempChar Like number
                tempElementCount = tempElementCount & tempChar
        End Select
        If i = maxIndex Then
            If Val(tempElementCount) = 0 Then
                tempElementCount = 1
            End If
            parsedElement.elementCount = Val(tempElementCount)
            tempParseFormula.Add(parsedElement)
            parsedElement.symbol = ""
            parsedElement.elementCount = 0
            tempElementCount = ""
            Exit While
        End If
        i += 1
        If compoundString(i) Like firstLetter Then
            If Val(tempElementCount) = 0 Then
                tempElementCount = 1
            End If
            parsedElement.elementCount = Val(tempElementCount)
            tempParseFormula.Add(parsedElement)
            parsedElement.symbol = ""
            parsedElement.elementCount = 0
            tempElementCount = ""
        End If
    End While
    Return tempParseFormula
End Function
```